# Check if hitTestObject finished with all the elements of an array

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an array with seven movieclips that hitTestObject a movieclip called ousiastikaChest. That's works fine. I want to check if all elements of that array had hitTestObject so a well done message to appear. This part of my code is wrong. Can anyone help me? Thank you

This is my code

```
 var circles:Array = [ous1,ous2,ous3,ous4,ous5,ous6,ous7];
 for each(var circleMC:MovieClip in circles)
 {
     circleMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp);
     circleMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropIt);
     circleMC.startX = circleMC.x;
     circleMC.startY = circleMC.y;
}

 function pickUp(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
     event.target.startDrag(true);
     event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);

 }

function dropIt(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
     event.target.stopDrag();

     if(event.target.hitTestObject(ousiastikaChest)){
         event.target.buttonMode = false;
         event.target.alpha = 0 
         event.target.x = ousiastikaChest.x;
         event.target.y = ousiastikaChest.y;
         ousiastikaChest.gotoAndPlay(2);
    }
    else
     {
         event.target.x = event.target.startX;
         event.target.y = event.target.startY;
         event.target.buttonMode = true;
    }
 }
 //problem with that part of the code
 for(var i:int = 0; i<circles.length;i++){
      if(circles[i].hitTestObject(ousiastikaChest)){
         feedback.text="Well Done";
      }
 }
```

Comment: Do you want to show the "Well done" message when the condition is true for all your circles or just one of them ?

Comment: When the condition is true for all my circles. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show the message when the condition (hitTest) is true for all your circles, you can use a `Boolean` var like this :

```
var show_message:Boolean = true;

for(var i:int = 0; i < circles.length; i++){
    // if the condition is false for only one item, so don't show the message
    if(!(circles[i].hitTestObject(ousiastikaChest))){
        show_message = false;
    }
}

if(show_message){
    // a trace for test, because sometimes text boxes don't show texts because of embedding fonts problem
    trace('Well Done');    
    feedback.text = 'Well Done';
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: It doesn' t work. It doesn' trace anything as well. No output, no compiler error.

Comment: @Marianna It doesn't trace anything that doesn't mean that the code is not working ! Try to verify if the condition is true for all your circles by adding a trace into the condition.

Comment: I add a trace into the condition and it seems that the conditions starts when i enter frame, before drag and drop factionality.Ok i found what was wrong. i paste the above code in a wrong possition.  It works just fine. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Marianna Yes, according to your code, it's a normal behavior. You can put that code into a function and execute it just after dragging all your circles.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved by two way 
1. This is simple . Whenever you `if(event.target.hitTestObject(ousiastikaChest)){` this become true, add 1 to a variable. eg:

```
var point =0 
if(event.target.hitTestObject(ousiastikaChest)){
point++;
}
```

Check the point is equal to 7 then show welldone.

2. The second way is different. Assign a class to the object. Inside the class declare a public boolean variable like isHit make it as false. Whenever the hittest occurs make this variable true. And finally check all the object's ishit variable is true or false.